# De quelle « raison » s'agit-il dans la locution « à raison de » ?

Tags: prépositions, locutions

Il est énoncé dans la page 84 de *Schaum's Outline to French Grammar* de Mary Crocker :

> **à raison de** = *at the rate of*

Je comprends la locution prépositionnelle « en raison de », signifiant « dû à », qui me paraît logique.

En outre, je trouve également logique ce qui est décrit [dans le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raison) :

> *À raison*. En étant dans le vrai; sans se tromper. *Il faudra trois jours à un spécialiste pour parvenir à ouvrir ce coffre blindé, réputé − à raison − inviolable* (*Le Figaro*, 6 mars 1987, p. 9, col. 2). 
>   *À tort* ou à raison*.

Pourquoi *à raison de* n'a-t-il rien à voir avec la raison ?

Comment: [Selon Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raison_d%27une_suite): _En mathématiques, la raison est la valeur qui permet de passer d'un terme au suivant dans certaines suites définies par récurrence_.

Comment: *À raison* a bien à voir avec la raison, mais le mot raison a plusieurs sens et dans les exemples que tu cites *à raison de*, *à raison* et *en raison de* le mot raison n'a pas le même sens.

Comment: @mouviciel: Merci bien! Je ne le savais pas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il faut se pencher sur l'histoire des mots *raison* et *ratio* qui sont des doublets. Et sur les différents sens que le mot *raison* a pris à travers les siècles. Trop nombreux pour qu'on les passe tous en revue ici, je vais tenter d'en aborder quelques uns et en particulier ce qui peut éclairer la question posée.

**Sources** de ce qui suit, *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* et *Le dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (les deux sld d'Alain Rey).

Les mots **raison** et **ratio** sont issus du latin *rationem*, qui vient lui-même de *reri* : « compter » et « penser ».
*Ratio* désigne le compte, puis la matière du compte.

De là sont issus de nombreux sens dérivés : *ratio* désigne la faculté de calculer, de réfléchir, le jugement, la méthode, la doctrine.

Le mot *raison* apparaît en 980 avec le sens de : ce qui est juste, équitable.

En ancien français on trouve un [*livre de raison(s)*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livre_de_raison) pour parler d'un livre de comptes. La raison c'est aussi (XV<sup>e</sup> siècle) la part de chaque associé dans une société commerciale (à rapprocher de l'évolution du mot qui va donnera le dérivé *ration*). De cette spécialisation du mot on passe à la « raison sociale » d'une entreprise commerciale.

En même temps *raison* continue d'exprimer la notion de rapport, de proportion.
En moyen français on dit *à la raison de* et de nos jours le "la" s'est perdu et on continue à dire *à raison de* pour signifier « en proportion de », 
« sur la base de ». On retrouve ce sens de *raison* dans les expressions mathématiques en « raison inverse », « en raison directe » etc. Ce sens de raison est traduit en anglais par *ratio*. Je laisserai les nombreux scientifiques qui peuplent ce forum rectifier ou développer (le terrain devient glissant pour moi).

C'est au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle qu’apparaît le mot *raison* pour désigner le principe explicatif rendant compte d'un fait, d'un événement. On trouve ce sens dans des expressions comme « rendre raison de quelque chose » (c'est à dire l'expliquer clairement), « sans raison » ou « avec raison », « en raison de » (à cause de).

Answer (score 1):

En plus court à raison désigne en réalité la ration, c'est à dire la mesure:
dans la phrase à raison de 2 fois par jour : pour une mesure de deux fois par jour

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé.